# MFMailComposeViewController Orientation in ipad

Tags: ipad, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

i am implemented MFMailComposeViewController in ipad application. It works great in Portrait mode. When i rotate it to Landscape mode its not completely fill the page. Is it possible to show the mail composer without any space.

Comment: You really should't ask your question in a code block.

Comment: here after i make it right.... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes i find the answer as just by include the line

`picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;`

in -(void)displayComposerSheet method.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, please press the ✔ next to it.

Comment: My code -(void)displayComposerSheet method worked good in iPhone but not in iPad.
-(void)displayComposerSheet
{
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
 picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
 NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"srikanth.rongali786@gmail.com"]; 
 [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
 [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:picker.view];
 [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
 [picker presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
 [picker release];
}

Comment: In code it is stopping at [picker presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
Thank You.